# Why do I get ImportError when trying to import Pandas Python module?

Tags: python

I installed the [Pandas module for Python 2.7](http://pandas.pydata.org/) using `apt-get`. However, when I try to import the module, it raises an `ImportError`:

```
 import pandas as pd
 File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    raise ImportError('ImportError: C extensions not built: if you installed already verify that you are not importing from the source directory')
```

The call in `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/__init__.py` is:

```
import pandas.lib as lib
except Exception:  # pragma: no cover
    import sys
    e = sys.exc_info()[1] # Py25 and Py3 current exception syntax conflict
    if 'No module named' in str(e):
        raise ImportError('C extensions not built: if you installed already '
                          'verify that you are not importing from the source '
                          'directory')
    else:
        raise
```

Why do I get `ImportError` and how do I solve this?

Following is what I get when trying to import the dependencies of Pandas in an interactive Python shell:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import dateutil
>>> import pytz
>>> import numexpr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numexpr
>>> import bottleneck
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bottleneck
```

Answer (score 2):

Following are the [dependencies for Pandas](https://github.com/pydata/pandas#dependencies):

- NumPy
- python-dateutil
- pytz

And the Pandas project list the following two as [highly recommended dependencies](https://github.com/pydata/pandas#highly-recommended-dependencies):

- numexpr
- bottleneck

It looks like `apt-get` only installed the required dependencies and not the highly recommended ones; as such you get an `ImportError` when trying to import `numexpr` and `bottleneck`. Installing these modules should most probably solve the problem.

Since, you are running Python 2.7 as evident from Python Traceback, install these two modules as suggested below:

- `numexpr` is present in Ubuntu's repositories. So, install it by running:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install python-numexpr
  ```
- `bottleneck` is not present in Ubuntu's repositories. So, install it using `pip`. We would also need to install `build-essentials` package in order to build `bottleneck`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install python-pip build-essentials
  sudo pip install bottleneck
  ```

Comment: Thanx Aditya, You're right. It works

Comment: It looks like apt-get only installed the required dependencies and not the highly recommended ones.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if a package was installed via `easy_install`, and now other dependency packages have been installed via PIP, this sort of issue can arise.

To fix, remove any/all modules installed via `easy_install` by `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/"module_name"`.

Then run `pip install "module_name"`.